# Null handling when Jersey unmarshals JSON via JAXB?

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jackson

Jersey appears to have a set of predetermined default values for JSON nulls while unmarshalling via JAXB: String => "", Integer => 0, ... is there anyway to easily control these values either with configuration or annotations?

Using Jersey's POJO mapping I get what I want, which is to map JSON null to Java null, but for other reasons we really need to use JAXB.

It seems like this should be simple however I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The JAXB (JSR-222) specification does not cover JSON-binding so what you are experiencing is Jersey code interacting with the JAXB reference implementation producing some odd results wrt null handling.  EclipseLink MOXy is a JAXB compliant implementation that also [offers JSON binding](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html) that has more natural null handling.

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    private String firstName;

    @XmlElement(nillable=true) 
    private String lastName;

}
```

If this was marshalled to JSON the result would be the following.  Null values are not marshalled to JSON unless they are annotated with `@XmlElement(nillable=true)`:

```
{
    lastName: null
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

**Jersey Integration**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html
- https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/json-moxy

Comment: What does the unmarshall look like? Do incoming JSON nulls get mapped to Java null or would they show-up in a String field as an empty String?

Comment: @Mike - Incoming nulls get mapped to nulls in the Java model.

Comment: Thanks Blaise, we'll take a look.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: Why is a nil JAXBElement marshalled to json-null, but json-null ist unmarshalled to null and not a nil JAXBElement? How can I differenciate between a absent property and a null-valued property?